# Export video to Live Photo

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, video, wallpaper

So everywhere I see how to convert a Live Photo into a video or a gif, but how do you save a video as a Live Photo?

The goal here is to take a video and make a Live Photo for use on iOS lock screen.

Answer (score 1):

[intoLive - Live Wallpapers app](https://itunes.apple.com/app/intolive-live-wallpapers/id1061859052) is the app you are looking for.

It takes a video and exports it to Live Photo which can be set as video wallpaper on supported devices.

Comment: Doesn’t this cost money? Also, if there a way to just do it with like Adobe Premiere or something?